# Create HTML in java with background image

Tags: java, android, html

I have created an html string in which I need to set the background image.

```
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String,String> hPlaceDetails){         


                    String backgroundImage = ??????

                    String name = hPlaceDetails.get("name");
        String icon = hPlaceDetails.get("icon");
        String vicinity = hPlaceDetails.get("vicinity");
        String lat = hPlaceDetails.get("lat");
        String lng = hPlaceDetails.get("lng");
        String formatted_address = hPlaceDetails.get("formatted_address");
        String formatted_phone = hPlaceDetails.get("formatted_phone");
        String website = hPlaceDetails.get("website");
        String rating = hPlaceDetails.get("rating");
        String international_phone_number = hPlaceDetails.get("international_phone_number");
        String url = hPlaceDetails.get("url");


        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        String data =   "<html>"+                           
                        "<body background="+backgroundImage+"><img style='float:left' src="+icon+" /><h1><center>"+name+"</center></h1>" +
                        "<br style='clear:both' />" +
                        "<hr  />"+
                        "<p>Vicinity : " + vicinity + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Location : " + lat + "," + lng + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Address : " + formatted_address + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Phone : " + formatted_phone + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Website : " + website + "</p>" +
                        "<p>Rating : " + rating + "</p>" +
                        "<p>International Phone  : " + international_phone_number + "</p>" +
                        "<p>URL  : <a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</p>" +         
                        "</body></html>";

        // Setting the data in WebView
        mWvPlaceDetails.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, mimeType, encoding, "");          
    }
```

Note: I have my background image (background9.png) in the location MyProject/res/drawable-xhdpi. Please suggest how I need to set

```
<body background="+backgroundImage+">
```

Comment: Set it as the path to the image.. You know the name of the image and where it is in the project. It should be trivial.

Comment: well I did that but its not working. I used \res\drawable-xhdp\background9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `\res\drawable-xhdp\background9.png` as the path as you mentioned in your comment, you should use:

```
<body background='file:///android_res/drawable/background9.png'>
```

I've just tested this and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a tag for android to clarify your question.

Anyway, you need to get a reference for your parent layout, by using `findViewById(R.id.yourActivitysParentLayout)`

You need then to set it's background using a ResourceManager. From the top of my head, the method name you will need is yourparent.setBackgroungDrawable(drawable). The drawable can be obtained from a resource manager instance.

This can all be avoided by setting it's background in the xml if possible by using `android:background="@drawable/background9" //sorry not sure if .png is needed. xhdp is not though.`

Comment: I tried that to by placing the 'android:background="@drawable/background9' in the <WebView> but still no help. I am setting an HTML in <WebView>. So I think I need to set the <Body background="?"> in <html>.

Comment: I don't think a webview can hava a background, as it get's it's background from html. you need to set the background directly in the html. That has to do with html itself, and not java. Handling html through java is indeed possible, though it is a completely different matter. I don't think I can serve any help with that.